# Were all Buddha's born in India?

Tags: theravada

As per below [*List*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_named_Buddhas#The_29_named_Buddhas) their was 28 buddhas with Gotama Buddha. so my question is did all the Budda's born on India (Jambuddeepa) in different times?

The names of the 28 Buddhas

Taṇhaṃkara

Medhaṃkara

Saraṇaṃkara

Dipankara

Koṇḍañña

Maṃgala

Sumana

Revata

Sobhita

Anomadassi

Paduma

Nārada

Padumuttara

Sumedha

Sujāta

Piyadassi

Atthadassi

Dhammadassi

Siddhattha

Tissa

Phussa

Vipassi

Sikhi

Vessabhū

Kakusandha

Koṇāgamana

Kassapa Buddha

Gotama Buddha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accprding to the records, within a *kappa* (world period), sometimes only one Buddha appears. It's hard to imagen that such as "India" is either linguistig nor geological, in it's location, even within a imagenable period very constant and "existing" in a sphere of common perception. It can be not valid said that such as India could be regarded as a certain place, and it's for sure not possible to imagen reasonable that such as India would appear for other Buddhas. Now think how the planet rushes even now through the worlds and minds of beings. Such as "India" was even at the time of our Buddha not "existentk in the sense it might be today common defined.

But let that question be a matter of stories, historical grasping and philosophy. How ever one feels common with, one might regard it who ever it might not cause one stress. To remind that form as well as perception are subject to change, would the wise remind not to grasp it otherwise, so that it will not unavoidable hurt.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*

Answer (score 0):

Well, all these Buddhas have Indian names.  In other places they have their places of birth, in India.  This can't be.  The time frame is too large.  They could not all be born in India.  They would have been preaching to dinosaurs.  The amount of time and place don't fit.  It makes no sense.